# How to fix UnicodeEncodingError when using unicode.encode('rot13')

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

The version of my python is 2.7.

For some reason, I need to use rot13 to convert a paragraph with encoding 'utf-8'. But when I run commands as followed:

```
s = u'€'
res = unicode.encode('rot13')
```

I get the following error message:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: character maps to `<undefined>`. How can I fix this error? I was trapped in this error for long time, and can't fix it by the method on Google.

Comment: What do you expect to get when you rot13 that character?

Comment: I want to insert some text to MySQL on server, but I can't insert text include keywords of MySQL, so I want convert the text by rot13. But some text include some characters like '€', when process these text, I get UnicodeEncodeError like this. After processing, '€' still is '€', but other keywords were replaced.

Comment: Why don't you just properly quote/escape the texts like everybody else, instead of doing such rot13 shenanigans?

Comment: I use Django's models to operate database. It works well on my computer but when I upload the back-up of the local database to server by phpmyadmin, it raise error because the reason I mentioned. So I have to do such rot13 trick

Comment: Then dont use phpmyadmin, I guess? Solving this issue via rot13 is not really the best way how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rot13 codec can't do this in Python 2. It's hardcoded to use charmap. Switch to Python 3 or just write your own rot13.

Comment: Thanks your answer, I will write my own rot13.